# Can I use a YN-E3-RT on the hotshoe of a YN-622C receiver?

Tags: yongnuo

I want to move my YN-E3-RT from the hotshoe to handheld to prevent camera movement between multiple exposures as I change settings. Will this work:  YN-622c transmitter on hotshoe to a YN-622c receiver that has a YN-E3-RT mounted on it? I want the YN-E3-RT to act as if it was on the hotshoe. All would be yongnuo.

For example, with the YN-622 transmitter on the camera hotshoe, a YN-E3-RT mounted on a YN-622 receiver as in the original question.  If the signals will work through the YN-622s, then I would have a handheld yn-e3-rt (it would think that it is on the camera hotshoe (I shoot in manual, multiple exposures of the same scene and need to make sure the images stay aligned.)

Is there someone with the equipment to test this setup before I buy the YN-622 triggers? If it works, use 1/200 sync and take a pic. The YN-E3-RT setup would be manual for setting the power level of the strobes (set in the grouping).

9/9/16 acquired 622c and tested - it does kinda of work, the lights fire but...
I have 3 600ex-rt speed lights, grouped a b c, at different power levels on the yn-e3-rt, however when triggered thru the yn622c, the yn622c overides the yn-e3-rt settings, changes it to ALL and resets the power levels to the whats in the yn622c-tx.  Is there any way to stop the yn622 from doing this ???

I did have some cheapo triggers that would work but they are very range limited.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Can you expand a little on your shooting scenario and how the YN-E3-RT can be both in your hand AND on a YN-622C acting as a receiver?

Comment: Please don't use answers to leave comments. We can see that your post was modified. Thanks!

Comment: Should it work, and I don't have the gear to test it, then I would expect some lag there. You may see black banding as a result, just something to be aware of.

Comment: There's no lag when using 622Cs for wireless HSS. If it works to allow the camera and YN-E3 RT to communicate at all I highly doubt there would be enough lag to affect sync speed. I use the 622Cs and I've never been able to find any way in which flash(s) connected to a Canon EOS camera vis the 622Cs acts differently than if the flash were attached directly to the hot shoe. Mechanical relays in old flash switching panels are much slower than IC based switches in modern wireless flash triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience using the YN622C system I would guess you probably could attach a YN-E3-RT to your camera using a set of YN622C transceivers. But I've never known of anyone actually doing it. The only way to find out if what you are proposing works is probably to try it yourself as I doubt anyone else here ever has. There may be issues between the 622C on the hot shoe and the YN-E3-RT
conflicting over which one gets to be the Master controller.

There is a much simpler and cheaper solution to using a YN-E3-RT without moving your camera when you touch the flash controller: An off camera hot shoe cord.

[https://www.amazon.com/Vello-TTL-Off-Camera-Flash-Cord-Canon/dp/B005GMWEI8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005GMWEI8)

[image]

Attach one end of the cord to your camera and the other end of the cord to your YN-E3-RT. The flecibility of the cord will prevent any movement of the controller from affecting the camera in much the same way that a wired shutter release works.

---

Regarding your 9/16 edit: You don't need the 622 at all if you attach the YN-E3-RT to the camera's hot shoe using a TTL cord.