# How to set up Yongnuo "Master" Off-Camera Flash

Tags: photography-basics

I need help in figuring out what flash equipment I would need for a real estate photography start-up. Camera is Nikon. I'm looking at the Yongnuo flashes and triggers because of price and for their good reviews. Here's what needs to happen.

1. 3 off-camera flashes - 2 will be on light stands and 1 on a monopod. I believe a trigger (i.e. YN-622N-TX) needs to be on top of the camera hot shoe.
2. Camranger - I should not touch the camera as I would be taking multiple photos of the exact same scene. I'll control camera settings and shoot from my iPad.
3. This is my question - I need to control the three flashes - power, zoom, etc. while not touching the camera. What equipment do I need?

What I gather is that the 3 flashes can be controlled in two ways - 1. thru the flash trigger (i.e. YN-622N-TX) on the camera or 2. by manually changing settings on each flash. #1 is not appropriate because I don't want to touch the camera/trigger and #2 takes time.

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Here's the Canon version of the exact same scenario: How to control wireless flashes without touching and moving the camera - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/82480/can-i-use-a-yn-e3-rt-on-the-hotshoe-of-a-yn-622c-receiver/82532#82532

Comment: # 2 also means that you don't need the TX, just another 622N on camera.

Comment: @Robin A single YN-622N and a YN-622N-TX are roughly the same cost. The TX gives much more functionality over controlling all of the flashes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [off-shoe TTL cord](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005GMWI0M) to attach the YN-622N-TX to the hot shoe. That way you can control the flashes from the transmitter without touching the camera. This works in much the same way that a wired remote shutter release does. The cord absorbs all of the movement and the camera remains stationary.